# Display progress bar based on download called by another class

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a windows form which has a download button. The download button creates another class' object and this object triggers the download. I have created a progress bar in the main windows form and want this progress bar to update as the file gets downloaded.

The main windows form calls the object as below :

```
Dim dwObj= Downloader()
dwObj.DownloadFileFromLocation(fileName, fileType)
```

The DownloadFileFromLocation method is defined as below in the Downloader class :

```
 Public Function DownloadFileFromLocation(FileName As String, FileType As String))
        Dim Address As String = "MyLINK"
        
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(MyLocalPath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MyLocalPath)
        End If
        
        Try
            Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
            If (FileType.Equals(MyFileType)) Then
                If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(MyLocalPath + FileName)) Then
                    AddHandler fileReader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged
                    fileReader.DownloadFile(Address, MyLocalPath + FileName)
                End If
            End If

            If (FileType.Equals(AWSGlobals.DWC)) Then
                If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(AWSGlobals.DWPath + FileName)) Then
                    fileReader.DownloadFile(Address, AWSGlobals.DWPath + FileName)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As HttpListenerException
            Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + Address + " - " + ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + Address + " - " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Now, I have defined a function to update the progress bar, but since its in another file, I get an error :

```
Private Sub Download_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Try
            ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(Math.Round((e.BytesReceived / e.TotalBytesToReceive) * 100, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Now I get the error, which I understand because Progress bar is declared in the main windows form

```
ProgressBar1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

The question is how can I handle this now. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Your Downloader should raise an event, and in the main form, you must subscribe to that event and respond by updating the progress bar accordingly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/walkthrough-declaring-and-raising-events

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/walkthrough-handling-events